# OpenCV Include error "Cannot open source file"

Tags: c++, opencv

I am new in OpenCV.  I had install Visual Studio 2015 and OpenCV3.1.
I had included all the dependencieas and include file location.
But I am getting error:

```
cannot open source file"opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
cannot open source file"opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp"
cannot open source file"opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
```

Anyone can help whats is the problem?

Comment: Did you add opencv's include folder path to `Additional Include Directories`?

Comment: Yes I had added the include folder path..

Comment: for both Debug and Release?

Comment: Yes.I follwed the tutorial from youtube : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l4372qtZ4dc

Comment: Well, the only problem I can think then is that you typed a wrong path. Try to copy-paste the path from `Additional Include Directories` and see if it contains the header files

Comment: Make sure whatever path you have added to your `Additional Include Directories` has inside of it the following folder: `opencv2` if it does not there is your problem!

Comment: ***Yes.I follwed the tutorial from youtube*** Tutorials on YouTube are often wrong.

Answer (score 0):

In the additional Include directories the path should be something like .. 'C:\OpenCV-3.0.0\opencv\build\include' once whether it is 
`#include "opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp"` or                                                `#include "opencv2/imgcodecs/imgcodecs.hpp"` because in the version i am using header file inside the folder imgcodecs.